# Are there an error handling API / framework in Java?

Tags: java, api, error-handling

On a Server there can occur different temporary (transient) errors. For example an OutOfMemoryError or a broken connection to a database.

I think it is a good idea to repeat such job a short time later. Of course it should not a endless loop because the error is not temporary.

Are there any good API to help with it? Or a guide how I can implement it self. It sould have parameter like:

- repeat count
- max execution time
- needed free memory
- etc

Comment: Just to pick a nit, OutOfMemoryErrors probably aren't transient; if you've got some data that requires more memory than your JVM is configured to use, retrying the job isn't going to help.

Comment: On a server a OutOfMemoryError occur in the most case because there are temporary to many clients requests. Some seconds later this can look others.

Comment: If you are getting OutOfMemoryError because of load, you need to throttle the load somehow (queue the requests or just refuse them).  OutOfMemoryErrors can occur *anywhere* as a result of memory usage elsewhere.  You can't just surround one part of the code with try/catch.

Answer (score 3):

This general idea is often called the Circuit Breaker pattern. Google has an [interesting list](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=circuit-breaker+pattern&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) of implementation ideas.